# .dst to .png file conversion using php or JavaScript or ASP.net

Tags: javascript, php

I unable to convert .dst image in .png format.
I already tried above conversion using php (ImageMagick commands) and Javascript but not found any solution.
Also check other javascript framework such as Fabric JS(Canvas).

I havent checked using ASP.net yet.

Comment: If dst is an embroidery file format, then Imagemagick cannot convert from or to it. I would suggest you search Google for such converters.

Comment: yes i found few plugin for the same but they provide paid API which is very expensive.